# Getting the Twitter user handle from a Dialogflow session

Tags: twitter, dialogflow-es

I am using the Twitter integration option with Dialogflow, and wondered if there is a way of getting the Twitter user handle/user Id from the Dialogflow session?

I cant see anything in the JSON messages that Dialogflow generates, so I am guessing not, but it's worth asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Your webhook will be passed information about the sender in the `originalRequest` field.

In the case of a direct message, you can find their handle under `originalRequest.data.direct_message.sender.screen_name`.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how I missed that, didn't look hard enough :(

Comment: Glad it's working for you! Please consider marking this answer correct.